# Review: why is there highlight only on suggested edits?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, suggested-edits, review, 10k-tools

When a suggested edit can be reviewed, we can see this:

[image]

However, it seems we don't have anything similar of other kinds of reviews, like "First posts" or "Close question". Why this? Can we do the same (with different colors or not) for the other ones?

The point is that we are sure that there are things to review when we click on the corresponding word (without having to refresh). Hence it will improve dynamism of our site.

Of course, we can add an other tab and refresh the page, but it is not in the spirit of highlight for suggested edits.

**Update:** maybe now it's easier to do with the new tab.

Comment: Is this 10k/20k+ only? I've never seen such a brown circle behind "review".

Comment: @Lord_Farin: Yes. It is.